# How to send an alert to user without sending him/her to the another page in react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing e-commerce app in react-native.Need help

> I am using react-navigation for routing.

is there any idea how to send alert to user that his/her item has been added to cart without sending him to cart page but the cart id??

```
cart(){
   let product_id = this.props.navigation.state.params.id;
   AsyncStorage.getItem('cart_id')
     .then((_id) => 
          API.post_data(_id, product_id )
              .then((data) => {
                  if(data){
                      alert(data.product_name + 'data success');
                     }     

      // If I use this,
      // this.props.navigation.navigate("Cart", {id:data.id);
      // This send an user to cart page as well.

                    else{
                        alert(data.error.message + 'failed')
                       }
                    })
                .catch(err => alert(err))
            })
}

       <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
          this.cart()
       }}
            >
       </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [React Native Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert) ?)

Comment: but how would alert send an id to another page.?

Comment: Do you use some data management system like redux? If so just set this value to store and pass it to another route/component.

Comment: If not you should lift-up state with needed value to some mutual parent component (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: it's quite difficult and different..or do you tell how it would be done with this code I mentioned above..Thanks...!

Comment: You have only two ways to pass parameters to screen: navigate to this screen with parameters or store needed data above the router and pass it as props

Comment: How would I pass props to event while calling cart .for instance in TouchableOpacity  onPress event caing this.cart()..